# Transforming a semi-colon delimited string into different columns and rows

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table like this:

```
| ID | Contact                                                                        |
|----|--------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| 1  | 05-01-23 03:30PM EDT; email@email.com; 05-01-23 11:00PM EDT; email2@email.com; |
| 2  | 05-03-23 06:30PM EDT; email3@email.com; 05-03-23 12:00PM EDT; email4@email.com; |
```

Is there a way to write a SQL query for Snowflake that transforms it to a table like this?

```
| ID | Timestamp            | Email            |
|----|----------------------|------------------|
| 1  | 05-01-23 03:30PM EDT | email@email.com  |
| 1  | 05-01-23 11:00PM EDT | email2@email.com |
| 2  | 05-03-23 06:30PM EDT | email3@email.com |
| 2  | 05-03-23 12:00PM EDT | email4@email.com |
```

So far, I've only seen solutions to separating text with delimiters to different rows and not both columns AND rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using [`SPLIT_TO_TABLE`](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/split_to_table) to split a string (based on a specified delimiter) into rows.

The formula `ROUND((INDEX-1.1)/2)` was used to calculate the commun index for each set of successifs Email and timestamp:

```
with cte as (
    SELECT * 
    FROM yourtable, LATERAL SPLIT_TO_TABLE(yourtable.Contact, '; ') s
    ORDER BY SEQ, INDEX
)
select *, ROUND((INDEX-1.1)/2)
from cte
```

Return :

| ID | CONTACT | SEQ | INDEX | VALUE | ROUND((INDEX-1.1)/2) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 05-03-23 06:30PM EDT; email3@email.com; 05-03-23 12:00PM EDT; email4@email.com; | 1 | 1 | 05-03-23 06:30PM EDT | 0 |
| 2 | 05-03-23 06:30PM EDT; email3@email.com; 05-03-23 12:00PM EDT; email4@email.com; | 1 | 2 | email3@email.com | 0 |
| 2 | 05-03-23 06:30PM EDT; email3@email.com; 05-03-23 12:00PM EDT; email4@email.com; | 1 | 3 | 05-03-23 12:00PM EDT | 1 |
| 2 | 05-03-23 06:30PM EDT; email3@email.com; 05-03-23 12:00PM EDT; email4@email.com; | 1 | 4 | email4@email.com; | 1 |
| 1 | 05-01-23 03:30PM EDT; email@email.com; 05-01-23 11:00PM EDT; email2@email.com; | 2 | 1 | 05-01-23 03:30PM EDT | 0 |
| 1 | 05-01-23 03:30PM EDT; email@email.com; 05-01-23 11:00PM EDT; email2@email.com; | 2 | 2 | email@email.com | 0 |
| 1 | 05-01-23 03:30PM EDT; email@email.com; 05-01-23 11:00PM EDT; email2@email.com; | 2 | 3 | 05-01-23 11:00PM EDT | 1 |
| 1 | 05-01-23 03:30PM EDT; email@email.com; 05-01-23 11:00PM EDT; email2@email.com; | 2 | 4 | email2@email.com; | 1 |

Using the conditional aggregation by grouping data by ID and the commun generated index well give us the expected output :

```
with cte as (
    SELECT * 
    FROM yourtable, LATERAL SPLIT_TO_TABLE(yourtable.Contact, '; ') s
    ORDER BY SEQ, INDEX
)
select ID, max(case when CONTAINS(VALUE, 'EDT') then VALUE end) as Timestamp,
           max(case when CONTAINS(VALUE, '@') then VALUE end) as email
from cte
group by ID, ROUND((INDEX-1.1)/2)
order by ID, Timestamp
```

| ID | TIMESTAMP | EMAIL |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 05-01-23 03:30PM EDT | email@email.com |
| 1 | 05-01-23 11:00PM EDT | email2@email.com; |
| 2 | 05-03-23 06:30PM EDT | email3@email.com |
| 2 | 05-03-23 12:00PM EDT | email4@email.com; |